# How to make mypy like my protocols that work at runtime with runtime_checkable

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I defined a couple of protocols like so:

```py
import json
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar, runtime_checkable

T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)
T = TypeVar('T')


@runtime_checkable
class SupportsRead(Protocol[T_co]):
    def read(self, __length: int = ...) -> T_co: ...


@runtime_checkable
class SupportsWrite(Protocol[T_co]):
    def write(self, data: str | bytes): ...


@runtime_checkable
class SerializerToString(Protocol):
    def dumps(self, value: Any, *argv, **kwargs) -> str: ...

    def loads(self, value: str | bytes, *argv, **kwargs) -> Any: ...


@runtime_checkable
class SerializerToFile(Protocol):
    def dump(self, value: Any, file: SupportsWrite[str | bytes], **kwargs) -> None: ...

    def load(self, file: SupportsRead[str | bytes], **kwargs) -> Any: ...


@runtime_checkable
class Serializer(SerializerToString, SerializerToFile, Protocol):
    pass


class MySerializer:
    def dumps(self, value: Any) -> str:
        return f"dumps {value}"

    def loads(self, value: str) -> Any:
        return f"loads {value}"


var1: SerializerToFile = json
var2: SerializerToString = json
var3: Serializer = json
var4: SerializerToString = MySerializer()

assert isinstance(var1, SerializerToFile)
assert isinstance(var2, SerializerToString)
assert isinstance(var3, Serializer)
assert isinstance(var4, SerializerToString)
print("everything ok")
```

It runs without error, but mypy marks all the assigments to `var1`-`var4` with errors like so:

```
test11.py:42: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type Module, variable has type "SerializerToFile")  [assignment]
test11.py:42: note: Following member(s) of "Module json" have conflicts:
test11.py:42: note:     Expected:
test11.py:42: note:         def dump(value: Any, file: SupportsWrite[Union[str, bytes]], **kwargs: Any) -> None
test11.py:42: note:     Got:
test11.py:42: note:         def dump(obj: Any, fp: SupportsWrite[str], *, skipkeys: bool = ..., ensure_ascii: bool = ..., check_circular: bool = ..., allow_nan: bool = ..., cls: Optional[Type[JSONEncoder]] = ..., indent: Union[None, int, str] = ..., separators: Optional[Tuple[str, str]] = ..., default: Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]] = ..., sort_keys: bool = ..., **kwds: Any) -> None
test11.py:42: note:     Expected:
test11.py:42: note:         def load(file: SupportsRead[Union[str, bytes]], **kwargs: Any) -> Any
test11.py:42: note:     Got:
test11.py:42: note:         def load(fp: SupportsRead[Union[str, bytes]], *, cls: Optional[Type[JSONDecoder]] = ..., object_hook: Optional[Callable[[Dict[Any, Any]], Any]] = ..., parse_float: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = ..., parse_int: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = ..., parse_constant: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = ..., object_pairs_hook: Optional[Callable[[List[Tuple[Any, Any]]], Any]] = ..., **kwds: Any) -> Any
test11.py:43: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type Module, variable has type "SerializerToString")  [assignment]
test11.py:43: note: Following member(s) of "Module json" have conflicts:
test11.py:43: note:     Expected:
test11.py:43: note:         def dumps(value: Any, *argv: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> str
test11.py:43: note:     Got:
test11.py:43: note:         def dumps(obj: Any, *, skipkeys: bool = ..., ensure_ascii: bool = ..., check_circular: bool = ..., allow_nan: bool = ..., cls: Optional[Type[JSONEncoder]] = ..., indent: Union[None, int, str] = ..., separators: Optional[Tuple[str, str]] = ..., default: Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]] = ..., sort_keys: bool = ..., **kwds: Any) -> str
test11.py:43: note:     Expected:
test11.py:43: note:         def loads(value: Union[str, bytes], *argv: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any
test11.py:43: note:     Got:
test11.py:43: note:         def loads(s: Union[str, bytes, bytearray], *, cls: Optional[Type[JSONDecoder]] = ..., object_hook: Optional[Callable[[Dict[Any, Any]], Any]] = ..., parse_float: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = ..., parse_int: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = ..., parse_constant: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = ..., object_pairs_hook: Optional[Callable[[List[Tuple[Any, Any]]], Any]] = ..., **kwds: Any) -> Any
test11.py:44: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type Module, variable has type "Serializer")  [assignment]
test11.py:44: note: Following member(s) of "Module json" have conflicts:
test11.py:44: note:     Expected:
test11.py:44: note:         def dump(value: Any, file: SupportsWrite[Union[str, bytes]], **kwargs: Any) -> None
test11.py:44: note:     Got:
test11.py:44: note:         def dump(obj: Any, fp: SupportsWrite[str], *, skipkeys: bool = ..., ensure_ascii: bool = ..., check_circular: bool = ..., allow_nan: bool = ..., cls: Optional[Type[JSONEncoder]] = ..., indent: Union[None, int, str] = ..., separators: Optional[Tuple[str, str]] = ..., default: Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]] = ..., sort_keys: bool = ..., **kwds: Any) -> None
test11.py:44: note:     Expected:
test11.py:44: note:         def dumps(value: Any, *argv: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> str
test11.py:44: note:     Got:
test11.py:44: note:         def dumps(obj: Any, *, skipkeys: bool = ..., ensure_ascii: bool = ..., check_circular: bool = ..., allow_nan: bool = ..., cls: Optional[Type[JSONEncoder]] = ..., indent: Union[None, int, str] = ..., separators: Optional[Tuple[str, str]] = ..., default: Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]] = ..., sort_keys: bool = ..., **kwds: Any) -> str
test11.py:44: note:     <2 more conflict(s) not shown>
test11.py:45: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MySerializer", variable has type "SerializerToString")  [assignment]
test11.py:45: note: Following member(s) of "MySerializer" have conflicts:
test11.py:45: note:     Expected:
test11.py:45: note:         def dumps(self, value: Any, *argv: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> str
test11.py:45: note:     Got:
test11.py:45: note:         def dumps(self, value: Any) -> str
test11.py:45: note:     Expected:
test11.py:45: note:         def loads(self, value: Union[str, bytes], *argv: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any
test11.py:45: note:     Got:
test11.py:45: note:         def loads(self, value: str) -> Any
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a way to please mypy with those protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go through the problems one by one.

Given the following protocols for file-like objects:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar, runtime_checkable

T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)


@runtime_checkable
class SupportsRead(Protocol[T_co]):
    def read(self, __length: int = ...) -> T_co: ...


@runtime_checkable
class SupportsWrite(Protocol[T_co]):
    def write(self, data: str | bytes) -> Any: ...
```

### `SerializerToFile`

Simply adjusting your protocol members' parameter names to reflect those of the corresponding functions in the `json` module fixes the issue:

```py
@runtime_checkable
class SerializerToFile(Protocol):
    def dump(
        self,
        obj: Any,                        # was called `value`
        fp: SupportsWrite[str | bytes],  # was called `file`
        **kwargs: Any,                   # was missing `Any` (optional)
    ) -> None: ...

    def load(
        self,
        fp: SupportsRead[str | bytes],  # was called `file`
        **kwargs: Any,                  # was missing `Any` (optional)
    ) -> Any: ...


import json

var1: SerializerToFile = json  # passes
```

### `SerializerToString`

Again, the names did not match, but also your protocol methods accept arbitrary positional arguments, which neither the `loads` nor the `dumps` function does:

```py
@runtime_checkable
class SerializerToString(Protocol):
    def dumps(
        self,
        obj: Any,       # was called `value`
        # *argv: Any,   # this needs to be removed
        **kwargs: Any,  # was missing `Any` (optional)
    ) -> str: ...

    def loads(
        self,
        s: str | bytes,  # was called `value`
        # *argv: Any,    # this needs to be removed
        **kwargs: Any,   # was missing `Any` (optional)
    ) -> Any: ...


import json

var1: SerializerToString = json  # passes
```

### `Serializer` (intersection)

With the fixed protocols from above, the intersection of both of them is also a valid annotation to use for the `json` module:

```py
...

@runtime_checkable
class Serializer(SerializerToString, SerializerToFile, Protocol):
    pass


import json

var1: Serializer = json  # passes
```

### Custom serializer

Now the custom serializer needs to be adjusted accordingly, so that it matches the protocol as well:

```py
...

class MySerializer:
    def dumps(self, obj: Any, **_kwargs: Any) -> str:
        return f"dumps {obj}"

    def loads(self, s: str | bytes, **_kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        return f"loads {s!r}"


var1: SerializerToString = MySerializer()  # passes
```

The first `loads` argument *must* accept `bytes` as well, since the protocol defines it as `str | bytes`. Subtypes are contravariant in their method parameters. So you could only *widen* the parameter types accepted by the serializer, never narrow it. Something silly like `str | bytes | tuple[Any]` for the first argument on your `loads` method would still work, but just `str` does not.

---

### Attempt at explanation

As opposed to the [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) type, where you may only define the types that parameters in certain *positions* of the callable take, the protocol methods are more specific, since Python does allow all "normal" arguments to a function call to be passed as keyword-arguments (i.e. by name).

The exceptions are variable-number positional arguments, defined via `*args` and arguments specifically defined as *positional-only* by having their parameters precede a `/` in the signature.

So if you say that something is a structural subtype of e.g. `SerializerToFile`, if it implements a method `dumps`, where the first parameter is "positional-or-keyword" and named `value`, you could then use an object of that type somewhere and call that method as `dumps(value=123)`. But the [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) method **can not** be called that way because its first `parameter` is named `obj`, so a call of `json.dumps(obj={})` works, whereas the call `json.dumps(value={})` would fail. Therefore `json` does not conform to the protocol.

Similarly, if your protocol allows "var. args" in a method, i.e. `dumps(obj: Any, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any)`, that means you might want to call that method on an instance of that type as `dumps({}, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, but that is *not* allowed for [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) because aside from the very first parameter it explicitly defines the rest as **keyword-only** (all following the `*`).

Comment: cool, thank. Now I wonder if there is a way to make to work with just str as opposed to `str | byte` for the custom one, maybe with some overload for each?

Comment: If you only need the protocol to annotate places where `loads` is **only** ever called with `str` anyway, then just annotate that `SerializerToString.loads` parameter as `str`. That should work. Again, contravariance in the method parameters means the `json.loads` should still remain compatible.